# Calculating rotation difference in polar coordinates

Tags: matlab, rotation, simulink

I've got a problem with substracting two polar coordinate rotations. The problem is when my car should pass the '6 oclock' rotation. From what I observed, rotation towards X axis equals 0, towards negative X axis equals +-pi. (EDIT: X axis is the vertical axis)

I've got the current rotation of the car "psi" and the polar coordinate of the goal position. I can't subtract them without this problem occurring. 
[image: Simulink model with car's movement]

Comment: Maybe is a silly quaetions, but are you using somewhere an `atan`? If that is the case than you should consider to use `atan2` instead (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html)

Comment: No `atan` or `atan2`. Where should I use it - replace `cart2pol` with it?
EDIT: atan2 works the same way - has the same problem.

Comment: Perhaps this is only my problem, but I dont understand what you problem is. Please add some matlab code with the input and desired output and what exactly your problem is. (read [ask]). A snapshot of your simulink model and som strange figure are not really helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with normalizing the car's rotation with `rem(u,2*pi)` (dunno why it wasn't from the start), then also used `rem(u,pi)` after subtracting CURRENT from GOAL rotation (so it won't overshoot).